# OneSignal Notification handler calling 'startActivity'

Tags: java, android, onesignal

when i tried to make setNotificationOpenedHandler method, taking this error:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

startActivity redline and saying "Cannot resolve method 'startActivity (android.content.Intent)'"

Full codes:
**ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;

class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {


    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }

        if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: That method is only available from a Context object, which your class is not

Comment: Alright got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {

    private Context mContext;

    public ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }

        if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```